# Async Await in C# causing extra iterations of list/enumerable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, iteration

I am using Async and Await in a small C# WPF Application so that I can stop the gui from being blocked while a long processing operation runs in the background. The context of my application is it is reading data from a CSV and converting it into an XML Document.

When I run the following with an input list count of 1999 items, I end up with a resulting iteration count of about 8000.

```
**** Main Thread ****
    outputItems = await CreateOutputItems(inputItems);
**** End Main Thread ****

public async Task<IEnumerable<ConvertedEntity>> CreateOutputItems(IEnumerable<InputEntity> inputItems)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => inputItems.Select(CreateOutputItemFromInputItem));
    }
```

And when I remove this and run it as a procedural loop in the main thread I get the correct 1999 iterations.

```
var convertedItems = new List<ConvertedEntity>();

foreach (var inputItem in inputItems)
{
      var outputItem = CreateOutputItemFromInputItem(inputItem);
      convertedItems.Add(outputItem);
}
```

Also I noted that the field inside my ConvertedEntity which contains the ID Number (which is just the loop/iteration number) is corrupted when using the async await. Eg, the values are 2000, 4000, 6000 through into the 30,000's. When I use the foreach loop, they are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the method and ensure that it isn't being fired multiple times.  When run procedurally, you might be blocking, thus preventing events from firing multiple times, while running async may let it run multiple times.

Comment: What happens if you do `foreach(item in inputItems.select(CreatOutputFromInputItem)){convertedItems.Add(item)}`

Comment: Breakpoint only hits once @JohnKoerner thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @CoolBlue The numbers are correct when doing this.

Comment: Ok, I just thought it would be a good idea to have linq in play in your test case as well. By the way, does CreateOutputItems need to be async? It's asynchronously returning an awaitable. Is that necessary? Can't it synchronously _return_ an awaitable?

Comment: Might help to share what CreateOutputItemFromInputItem looks like.

Comment: Putting the `Select` in the `Task.Run` doesn't really do anything. The background thread is just building the LINQ query, not executing it. Look up LINQ deferred execution and sequence reification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `int` input parameter to your method so that you can use the version of `Select` with a index and then use that index `i` to correctly set your `ID`

```
public ConvertedEntity CreateOutputItemFromInputItem(InputEntity x, int i) 
{  
  // now use i to set the ID
```

Add also a `.ToList()` after the `Select(CreateOutputItemFromInputItem)` so that it executes it in the `Task.Run`

Comment: Putting the ToList fixed it. So it must have indeed been a problem with the actual execution of the LINQ not happening in the async await task.